# The string is converted to an array and used in the query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry for my english!

I think my question is stupid, but i don't know how do it. I have in database string (u_liked) into сompleted (1 2 3), and me need so that every symbol(digit) in this line, insert into value and than value insert in query.

```
if( isset($_GET["email"]) && !empty($_GET["email"]) ) {
     $conn = new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.ru", "***", "***", "u858836722_testk");
     $email=$_GET["email"];
     $email = stripslashes($email);
     $email = $conn->real_escape_string($email);  

    $check="SELECT u_liked FROM users WHERE u_id = '".$email."'";
    // 
    $rs1 = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1);

    $row = stripslashes($row['u_liked']);
    $row = $conn->real_escape_string($row);

// Don't work query
    $query="SELECT p_id, p_name, p_description, p_image_id, p_price, p_add  FROM products where p_id ='".$row."' ";

    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $outp = "";
   while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"p_id":"'  . $rs["p_id"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_name":"'   . $rs["p_name"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_description":"'   . $rs["p_description"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_image_id":"'   . $rs["p_image_id"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_price":"'. $rs["p_price"]     . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_add":"'. $rs["p_add"]     . '"}';
}
    $has_more=2;

  $outp ='{"has_more":'.$has_more.',"records":['.$outp.']}';
    $conn->close();
    echo($outp);    
}
```

But when one character is written in the database, I get

```
{"has_more":2,"records":[{"p_id":"3","p_name":"Готель: Кремінь","p_description":"Телефон: 05367 92300","p_image_id":"chicken_maharaja","p_price":"вулиця Ігоря Сердюка, 1, Кременчук, Полтавська область, 39605","p_add":"http://www.kreminhotel.com.ua/"}]}
```

and it's work

UPDATE 
It's working!

```
if( isset($_GET["email"]) && !empty($_GET["email"]) ) {
     $conn = new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.ru", "u858836722_testk", "80040163q", "u858836722_testk");
     $email=$_GET["email"];
     $email = stripslashes($email);
     $email = $conn->real_escape_string($email); 
    $check="SELECT u_liked FROM users WHERE u_id = '".$email."'";
    $rs1 = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1);    
    $row = explode(' ',$row['u_liked']);
    $row = array_map('intval',$row);


    $query="SELECT p_id, p_name, p_description, p_image_id, p_price, p_add  FROM products where p_id IN (".implode(',',$row).")";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $outp = "";
   while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"p_id":"'  . $rs["p_id"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_name":"'   . $rs["p_name"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_description":"'   . $rs["p_description"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_image_id":"'   . $rs["p_image_id"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_price":"'. $rs["p_price"]     . '",';
    $outp .= '"p_add":"'. $rs["p_add"]     . '"}';
}
    $has_more=2;

  $outp ='{"has_more":'.$has_more.',"records":['.$outp.']}';
    $conn->close();
    echo($outp);    
}
```

Comment: I hope those aren't your real credentials, if so reset them.

Comment: Which column does `p_id` map to in the other query? You might even be able to do this with 1 query using `join`s.

Comment: I'm just trying to program:(

Comment: The update you made doesnt make sense to me. Can you show what you mean by a single character works? You need to reset your credentials, that update doesnt help your site's security.

Comment: @S.Oleg I've removed your MySQL username and password.. because you have posted them to a public forum you should change your MySQL username and password immediately

Comment: table "users" colunm "u_liked" = colun "p_id" tables "products"

Comment: Okay, I think you could just do: `SELECT p.p_id, p.p_name, p.p_description, p.p_image_id, p.p_price, p.p_add  FROM products as p join users as u on u.u_liked = p.pid where u.u_id = '".$email."'"`

Comment: One request, but this is the correct syntax SELECT p.p_id, p.p_name, p.p_description, p.p_image_id, p.p_price, p.p_add FROM products ??? u.u_liked = p.pid where u.u_id = '".$email."'"  Sorry i am stupid

Comment: ohh sry i understand

Comment: So that works for you?

Comment: Hmm i use (SELECT p_id, p_name, p_description, p_image_id, p_price, p_add FROM products join users on u_liked = p_id where u_id = 'sovaoleg82@gmail.com';) in phmyadmin and I get an empty string

Comment: When in column u_liked one symbol (3 )your query work. But when in column u_liked more than one symbol (3 1) query is getting empty.

Comment: Use the `@` so notifications are sent. Can your provide an example(s)? The question is unclear to me currently.